# Disable all but few warnings in gcc

Tags: gcc

In gcc -w is used to disable all warnings. However in this case I can't enable specific ones (e.g. -Wreturn-type).

Is it possible to disable all warnings, but enable few specific ones?

As a workaround, is there a way to generate list of all -Wno-xxx at once? And will it help? I wouldn't want to do this manually just to find out that it is not equal to -w.

Comment: That's odd. You usually should **enable** all warnings and disable specific ones...

Comment: Yes, you are right, you know better! But let's imagine that I have a legacy project with 4 mlns lines of code where I would like to find specific errors.

Comment: Well, if you just specify `-Wreturn-type` (no other warning-related flags), doesn't that do what you want?

Comment: No, there're warnings enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to get an `WARN_OPTS` variable suitable for injecting directly into your `Makefile`:

```
gcc --help=warnings | awk '
    BEGIN       { print "WARN_OPTS = \\" }
    /-W[^ ]/    { print $1" \\"}
' | sed 's/^-W/    -Wno-/' >makefile.inject
```

This gives you output (in `makefile.inject`) like:

```
WARN_OPTS = \
   -Wno- \
   -Wno-abi \
   -Wno-address \
   -Wno-aggregate-return \
   -Wno-aliasing \
   -Wno-align-commons \
   -Wno-all \
   -Wno-ampersand \
   -Wno-array-bounds \
   -Wno-array-temporaries \
    : : :
   -Wno-variadic-macros \
   -Wno-vector-operation-performance \
   -Wno-vla \
   -Wno-volatile-register-var \
   -Wno-write-strings \
   -Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant \
```

Once that's put in your actual `Makefile`, simply use `$(WARN_OPTS)` as part of your `gcc` command.

It may need a small amount of touch up to:

- get rid of invalid options such as `-Wno-`;
- fix certain `-Wno-<key>=<value>` types; and
- remove the final `\` character.

but that's minimal effort compared to the generation of the long list, something you can now do rather simply.

When you establish that you want one of those warnings, simply switch from the `-Wno-<something>` back to `-W<something>`.